# Why can I not get past Username/Password/Login (Click)?

Tags: swiftui, appium, webdriver-io

I have an app with a login screen. I am exploring making automated tests for my app. I cannot get past the login screen.

The screen has two text fields, a secure text field, and a button.  I need to enter a base URL into the first and a username into the second text fields, a password into the secure text field and click the login button.

Th app hangs when I click the login button.  In the simulator if I click the login button there (using the URL/username/password entered by the simulator) it works normally

Here is the WD code:

```
// Requires the admc/wd client library
// (npm install wd)
// Then paste this into a .js file and run with Node 7.6+

const wd = require('wd');
const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
const caps = {"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPad Pro (9.7-inch)","automationName":"XCUITest","uuid":"E85ADF43-A1D0-472D-909A-B90E11767266","app":"/Users/user/Documents/GIT/B52/build/Release-iphonesimulator/B52FloorManagement.app"};

async function main () {
  await driver.init(caps);
  let el1 = await driver.elementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name=\"baseURLEntry\"]");
  await el1.sendKeys("http://example.com/login");
  let el2 = await driver.elementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name=\"userNameEntry\"]");
  await el2.sendKeys("XXXXXXXX");
  let el3 = await driver.elementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField[@name=\"passwordEntry\"]");
  await el3.sendKeys("XXXXXXX");
  let el4 = await driver.elementByAccessibilityId("loginButton");
  await el4.click();
  await driver.quit();
}

main().catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the virtual keyboard.

It was not visible in the screen displayed in the Appium Desktop app, but adding

```
  let el4 = await driver.elementByAccessibilityId("loginButton");
  await (new wd.TouchAction(driver))
    .tap({x: 946, y: 723})
    .perform()
  await el4.click();
```

The `.tap({x: 946, y: 723})` closes the virtual keyboard.  Then it worked.

It is odd because the `await el4.click()` is on the element itself.  But it must be inactivated when covered up by the on screen keyboard